# C# UWP Serial Communication Does Not Connect

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

i am creating serial communication program using UWP..

Serial Communication does not connect.
'device' is not captured. returns null.

code is here.

```
// Get a device selector from the given port name
string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(portName);

// Get a list of devices that match the given name
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector, null);

        // If any device found...
        if (devices.Any())
```

and then, i added that code in Package.appxmanifest in UWP Project.

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

but it does not work..

However, i am creating the serial communication module in class library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code in class library is the same like write in your UWP project. You should check the problem yourself first with the official [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess).Try this sample and connect your device with this sample. If the offical sample works without problem then it means your device do not have any problem. You need to check the difference between your project and the offical sample. For example, Did initialized the deviceWatcher? Did you start it?

If you need further help, maybe you need to clarify your device in detail and read this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us a sample.